# How can I increase the frequency of xticks/ labels for dates on a bar plot?

Tags: python, date, matplotlib, plot, bar-chart

I am trying to increase the xtick and label frequency of dates on a barplot. It currently puts labels for every 2nd month, and I'd like to increase this to every month.

The code I have so far is:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(1,1,1)

# defining the spacing around the plots
plt.subplots_adjust(left = 0.125, bottom = 0.1, right = 0.9, top = 0.9, wspace = 0.2, hspace = 0.35)

handles = []        # for bar plot  

bar1 = ax.bar(dates, clim[loc,:], label = 'climatology (1981 - 2013)', color='darkgray', width=width_arr[:], linewidth=0, alpha=0.5)

handles.append(bar1)

bar2 = ax.bar(dates, chirps[i,loc,:], label = str(year1), color = 'blue', width=width_arr[:], linewidth=0, alpha=0.45)
handles.append(bar2)


# setting the plot tick labels   
for tick in ax.xaxis.get_major_ticks():
    tick.label.set_fontsize(10)

for tick in ax.yaxis.get_major_ticks():
    tick.label.set_fontsize(10)

ax.set_ylabel("Precipitation", fontsize=10)

# plotting the legend within the plot space
plt.legend( loc = 'upper left', numpoints=1, ncol = 3, prop={'size':10})
plt.ylim(0, 110)

# rotating the tick marks to make best use of the x-axis space
plt.xticks(rotation = '25')
```

Comment: The code you have provided isn't so helpful as we don't know what `dates` or `clim` look like. Try to add a minimum working example that shows what you have, don't include things like `plt.subplots_adjust` that aren't relevant. This will improve the quality/quantity of answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the xtick loactions in the `xticks` command. Therefore, in your case this should do the trick: Instead of

```
plt.xticks(rotation = '25')
```

use

```
plt.xticks(dates,rotation = '25')
```

---

Here's a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that illustrates your question and the fix.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# generate random data
x = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
y = np.random.rand(2,5)

# setup the plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(1,1,1)

# plot the data, only the bar command is important:
bar1 = ax.bar(x, y[0,:], color='darkgray', width=0.5, linewidth=0, alpha=0.5)
bar2 = ax.bar(x, y[1,:], color = 'blue', width=0.5, linewidth=0, alpha=0.45)

# defining the xticks
plt.xticks(rotation = '25')
#plt.xticks(x,rotation = '25')

plt.show()
```

This will generate the following figure:

[image: question]

In this figure, we see many more labels than we hoped for - which is the opposite of what you had, however, the answer is the same.
Now, if you change the `plt.xticks` command (in the example above, you can comment one line and uncomment the other), the figure will change to:

[image: answer]

The fact that the y-data has changed (due to the call of `np.random` is irrelevant. You can, however, see that now we only have x-ticks at the locations given in `x`.

If you want to skip certain labels, I recommend utilizing [numpy's `arange`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) function. The `arange`, unlike `linspace`, allows for a fixed increment (the third input argument). You can replace the `plt.xticks(x,rotation='25')` line with the code below for an example:

```
# defining the xticks
names = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']

x_tick_location = np.arange(np.min(x),np.max(x)+0.001,2.0)

x_tick_labels = [names[x.index(xi)] for xi in x_tick_location]

plt.xticks(x_tick_location,x_tick_labels,rotation = '25')
```

This will give you the following plot:

[image: answer 2]

There are a few things worth pointing out:

- I introduced a list `names` that contains strings to be used as tick labels. I strongly advise against setting labels like this, because it decouples your tick labels from your data. Here, it helps illustrate the workings of `xticks`.
- The tick locations are defined using `np.arange` as mentioned above. Between the `min` and `max` entries of `x`, we increment by `2` in this example. It may help to add a small amount to the `max` value to ensure it can be considered (this has to do with floating point arithmetic).
- This command `[names[x.index(xi)] for xi in x_tick_location]` creates a list by taking each element from `x_tick_location`, finding its index in the original `x` and using that index to select the corresponding element in `names`.
- Last, you pass both the tick locations and the tick labels to the `xticks` command.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This seems very close to the answer I'm looking for. Ideally I'd like to plot the dates; there are 72 bars for the year (6 for each month), and I'd like to plot the month labels against the first bar of each month e.g. using x = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar' etc]. Is it possible to set the xticks to label every 6th bar?

Comment: that's perfect! Thanks very much for your help and taking the time to write such a detailed answer. I would vote your answer up but don't currently have enough voting power.